# Database Cardinality tables relationship

Tags: mysql, database, relational-database, foreign-key-relationship, cardinality

[Here is my database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dmLlT.png)

The problem that I have is that i dont really know the cardinalities specially on the cart table to product table relationship i dont know if is done the right way help please i just started in database.